# How to repeat records in access table number of times

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need your assistance to figure out how to achieve the following in MS access database.
I have a table with a lot of columns but one of them has a numeric value that will be used as how many times will the record will be repeated.

I need to make another table with repeated records based on Count column.

Answer (score 2):

Build a numbers (aka tally) table (you can google it). I'll call it tblNumbers. Then all you need to do is create a query `SELECT <yourTable>.* FROM <yourTable>, tblNumbers WHERE tblNumbers.Number <= <yourTable>.<numberField>`

Comment: Thank you. I have used this kind of table before without knowing they are called "tally table" and what cool [things](http://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/) you can do with them.